# The folders that my app makes with Rest drive API do not appear in my google drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am making an application with laravel that will make folders in google drive, it worked but with oauth 2.0 the user interface have to refresh the token and in this application we do not have any users, for this problem I used "service accounts for applications". I know there are folders created because my application can find them (their name and id) but they do not appear in my drive. My main question is where are these folders and why are they there and not in my google drive?

Comment: they aren't in YOUR drive because they are in the SERVICE ACCOUNT's drive. This question has been asked countless times on SO so I suggest check the similar questions list.

Comment: @pinoyyid preach it :D